# How to get INC from top script in PERL

Tags: perl

I have 2 script: a.pl with inside require param.pl, b.pl also require param.pl:

a.pl:

```
require param.pl;
system "perl b.pl";
```

b.pl:

```
require param.pl;
#do smthing
```

So, do we have anyway that b.pl script don't need require param.pl and using it from a.pl.

Thanks

Comment: What is inside of those scripts? Do you have `package`s in there? Or just subs? Or just a bunch of code that gets run when it gets `require`d? Please [edit] your question and include a [mcve].

Comment: You are calling `b.pl` as an external program.  Assuming no particular details about what is in those scripts, `b.pl` needs to have what it needs to have in order to run.  However, details can change that in many ways.  But, above all, please follow all advice given in the comment by [simbabque](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1331451/simbabque)

Answer (score 0):

No.

`b.pl` doesn't know that it was started from `a.pl`.  And whether or not it was doesn't make a difference to the Perl interpreter.